# Flex: change containers size to wrap the content

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm using TitleWindow with PopupManager.

I programmatically add the children to my TitleWindow and I would like the TitleWindow changing its size in order to avoid scroll-bars.

Is there any property to mek the windows wrapping the content in Flex ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do this is to give it a minHeight and minWidth, but no height or width properties. That way it shrinks to fit the content.

Be careful, though. If you have too much content it can go off the screen, so set a maxHeight and maxWidth. Or else resize title window based on screen loc and dimensions. Then you still have to handle scrollbars, but it happens much less often.